# Visual Studio Apache Cordova browser app

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I have been asked to develop an Apache Cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 that will simply load a website after login then the website will function as per its own functionality. And the app needs to work on Android, Apple & WP. I thought I had done it as samples are so simple but I cannot get it to work. Can somebody please point me in the direction of sample code that does this.

I have tried the InAppBrowser package but it does not load anything, it simply shows a page with my commands and no error information.

I have also tried putting my website into the  `<content src="index.html" />` section in the config.xml but then it doesn't even build.

It does not seem like using IFrames are a good idea either.

Any help will be appreciated. I really thought this would be simple.

Answer (score 1):

@Adriaan Davel, Okay. Nicely worded post. Thanks for doing that.

**QUOTE**

> I have been asked to develop an Apache Cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 that will simply load a website after login then the website will function as per its own functionality.

**Reply:**
*You can't do that.* It is not allowed. It is against all security protocols for *mobile app* development. You can do this with *web app*, but not *mobile app* - not even with *hybrid app* (like Cordova/Phonegap).

The best that you can do is load a webpage from the *device*, then login to the server. You are allowed to exchange data with the server, but you are *not* allowed to load a webpage from a remote webserver – with one exception.

**The One Exception**
You can load a webpage from a webserver in the [InAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin. In theroy, the App can pass data to the webpage, but it cannot receive data from the webpage. In addition, you **cannot** use any of the *Cordova API*s. This includes, but is not limited to, `device`, `File`, and `Geolocation`. You can in their place use the [HTML5 APIs](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/a-5-minute-overview-of-all-new-javascript-apis-in-html5.html) ([SEARCH](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+web+api)). Again, you have not access to the *Cordova APIs*

The typical way this is done is to have a REST API server that handles all the mobile data, then passes that data to the webserver - usually through a database. The point being there is no direct communication between the mobile client and the webserver. Webservers are considered too untrustworthy.

**The `whitelist` system**

*Brand new* This has been tripping up alot of developers. It tripped you too.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
There is a trick in there that explains how to get around this temporarily.
(Use: `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`)

**Code and Examples**

I have lots of examples for you, but they are not all up to date. The best example I have is this boilerplate: [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate5](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate5)

Here is the Blog Post: [Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iOS](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html) You want to use Boilerplate5

[Ten (10) Phonegap Demo Apps with Source Code](https://jssnippets.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/ten-10-phonegap-demo-apps-with-source-code/)
These demo apps are out of date. They need to have the `whitelist` added.

NOTE: I have three blogs 
[one](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/),
[two](https://unbot.wordpress.com/),
[three](https://jssnippets.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the information, I will work through it over the next few days. For a start we are actually just looking for a "web browser wrapper app", we are still building our POC to raise funding. I have tried the InAppBrowser like I mentioned but could not get it to work. For now I think this will get me close to where I want to start: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=en

Comment: Sorry I don't have an inAppBrowser yet. I will by this time next week.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has ever tried to load a remote webpage that happens to contain the cordova.js file as a resource into a Cordova webView? (make sure the remote content handles the deviceReady requirement for cordova.js).