# Phonegap app loading an external page

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Phonegap app loading an external page that preferably can access the cordova API to use camera action. Are there any options?

It cant open an external browser :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Read this: [(....) Cordova browser app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771290/visual-studio-apache-cordova-browser-app/33795635#33795635)

Comment: Thanks it does answer the question

Comment: Sorry. I did not give you an answer. I was too tired by the time I posted this response.